# Bamboo Release Versioning with Build Metadata

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am having difficulties trying to get parameterising of the Release versioning working with a Metadata field generated by the build process.

I am trying the use the release versioning with the bamboo parameter ${bamboo.TagBuildTriggerReason.tagName} to name the tag triggered release with a human readable label. However it seems that the Metadata parameters are not accessible because the variable never expands with the data from the build.

I have tried to create a variable on the build plan with this tagName parameter, but it seems that it doesn't ever get assigned.

Is it because only after or during the build the metadata tags are available and not before?

How can I get the tagName (git tag) into the release version name?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using version 8.1.2 of Atlassin Bamboo